# How to create hyperlink pointing into a Lotus Notes legacy application?

Tags: email, lotus-notes, hyperlink

We have a legacy application in Lotus Notes which I occasionally need to direct others to through either email or a web page.  I've had a look and Notes supports right-click->Copy as link which gives me the following on the clipboard:

```
TITLE
<NDL>
<REPLICA 41256489:003B32D7>
<VIEW OF23697E95:6CDA5D6D-ON412564C7:00553BC3>
<NOTE OF6BCA8821:34ABD6F6-ONC12577C8:0034BEF2>
<HINT>CN=XXX/O=YYY</HINT>
<REM>....</REM>
</NDL>
```

(slightly anonymized).

How can I create a hyperlink which - when clicked - allow others to open Notes to this location?

Note:  We run 5.0.11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, right click-> Copy like above. Then, in a new memo, highlight the text you want to make into a hyperlink and go to Create -> Hotspot -> Link Hotspot. A little window will popup. At the right hand side of the Value field, there is a paste button. Click that to paste your info. Then close the window and send the message. That text will be a link to whatever you pasted in.

If you want to play around with URLs and such, that same Link Hotspot can link to URLs by changing the type from Document to URL and then just setting the value.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Accepted on good faith.  I cannot test this before the bounty runs out.

Comment: When reading the received mail in Outlook, the link looks like notes://AAR/412568F00043E073/126963B27AE3C93E412568EF004CE433/0FA0088F0F40E32FC125781B003A5524, which Outlook considers a potential security concern, and when asked to continue I'm informed that "The parameter is incorrect".  Is there an additional trick?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/961812

Comment: Oh, maybe the url is formatted wrong? When I do it, it looks like "Notes://server.name.com/replica-number-no-colon/view-number-no-OF-no-colon/note-number-no-colons-no-dashes-no-initial-OF" When I added that as the address for a hyperlink in Word and Ctrl+clicked it, it went to the right email in notes.

Comment: If you want to construct a notes:// URL manually, it's of the structure:


    notes://servername/databaseName/viewName?OpenView or notes://servername/__dbReplicaID/viewUNID?OpenView for a view
    notes://servername/databaseName/0/documentUNID?OpenDocument or notes://servername/__dbReplicaID/0/documentUNID?OpenDocument for a document

You can leave the server name blank (so the protocol starts with notes:///) if you want to access a local database, view, etc.

Comment: From here: http://www.nsftools.com/tips/NotesTips.htm

Comment: My organization has locked down the legacy notes database so we can't create or send new emails from Notes.  However @slhck's Address Bar trick still works (and is much easier to boot)!

Answer (score 4):

Activating Address Bar:

- Right click on anywhere of Toolbar: A menu will pop-up
- Tick *Address*

Get Link:

- Select the document that you wish to get the link to
- Click the *Down Arrow* twice at the end of *Address Bar*

The document link will show in the *Address Bar*.

Comment: This solution is MUCH easier than the one above.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

First, in Notes, select View > Toolbar >
and then select "Address".

Then, find the link for a specific document:

- Open the document
- Click in the the address field to highlight whatever is there, hit delete to clear it
- Click once on the drop down arrow for the address field
- The address that shows up is the URL for the document
- Copy the link, and to test, paste in a browser, like any other URL.  It will open up the document in notes.

Comment: Is this valid for Notes 5.0.11?

Answer (score 1):

Try this
On the teamroom entry, right click, select "Document Properties", click on the <+> tab.  The link will show in the Identifier box.